# How can I perform a regular, automated housekeeping task in an MVC4 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automation, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I am using the default Account controller provided by the project template as is, with SimpleMembership. However, I need to perform two email based verifications before the user is finally vetted and allowed to use the system. I want to avoid temporarily storing user information, including password, before calling `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount`.

I'll make that call right at the beginning, after the user submits their registration form, then remove the user if either email verification fails, but I need that automated code to check for verifications that are timed out or declined.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a variation of the [email confirmation process as described here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html).  Go ahead and create the account using confirmation, but you control when final confirmation is complete by calling [WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569286%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).  Until that time the user will not have access. You can maintain state information on the users confirmation process by [customizing the UserProfile](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html); adding properties that indicate what stage they are in in your custom confirmation process.

I would also add a property that indicates the date and time that they initially registered for automatic cleanup. You can run a scheduled process that queries the UserProfile table to see if there are any records where the registration date has aged sufficiently and they have not completed the registration process, deleting them. There are some [tricks on deleting accounts in SimpleMembership that you can read about here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/trouble-deleting-users-in.html).

Comment: +1 for the deletion trick, but my question was really about running the scheduled process in the MVC application. Is there some mechanism, or do I just check if a date has changed in every `Application_Start` and if so run the cleanup?

Comment: There really is not a clean way to schedule a process in MVC. You could put the task in the Application_Start, but it will only fire when the app changes or the app pool recycles.  I guess you can set the app pool to recycle more often but that may have other side effects.  If you have full access to the server that the app is deployed on I would create a Window Service that periodically performs this task or use the Windows Task Scheduler to run a console application to do this.  Or you could expose a Web API that does this and have an external application call it periodically.

Comment: Yes, it isn't clean. I do have full control of the web server, luckily, and I think a scheduled app is best, as it can easily be used ad-hoc as well.